# USB detected as a legacy boot device only

Tags: windows, bios, uefi, windows-installation, rufus

- Windows 11 Pro installation USB flash drive is detected as a legacy boot device only
- When I open setup.exe, it shows this error:

> Use the other installation disc that says 64-bit. When you insert it, Windows Setup will restart automatically.

- When I open setup.exe that is in sources folder, it shows this error:

> This 32-bit version of Windows cannot be installed to an EFI-based computer. Installation cannot proceed. Use a 64-bit version of Windows to install to an EFI-based computer.

- ISO is written to USB using Rufus 3.19 as GPT, with the option **Standard Windows Installation**
- There is a drive called Local Disk, containing a folder called EFI
- I have Windows 10 x64 installed

Comment: Why don't you use Microsofts Windows 11 Media Creation Tool. It downloads the necessary files and creates a bootable USB stick that works.

Comment: Because internet interruption will cause the whole download progress to cease!

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/x6Ft4jP

Comment: There isn’t a 32-but version of Windows 11. Do you currently have a 32-bit version of Windows 10 installed? [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: You should be able to just install Windows 11 64-bit fresh (you cannot upgrade a 32-bit system). The download is about 3 GB. Will your internet not handle that?

Comment: Thanks. It unexpectedly worked (read the update), but in some cases, I have to use Rufus instead of Media Creation Tool; so I want to understand why it didn't work?

Comment: @John - You cannot run a 64-bit executable if your running a 32-bit install, you cannot install a 64-bit Windows install from within a 32-bit install

Comment: @AZeed - You haven’t provided enough information to diagnose the reason it wasn’t working

Comment: You cannot run a 64-bit executable if your running a 32-bit install,  -- Yes of course, which is why I said to download the 64-bit ISO.  You can go from there to format and install.

Comment: Based on the answer that was submitted sounds like the author simply downloaded the incorrect version

Comment: @Ramhound, the version is correct, but I used wrong image option in Rufus application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Media Creation Tool and it worked!

Note: If you still want to use Rufus, this problem can also be fixed by selecting **Standard Windows 11 Installation** option in image options